# Is it just me or TOP Joomla Cart Extensions don't work on iPhone and Kindle Fire

Tags: ios, iphone, joomla, kindle-fire

I hope someone in here can confirm or deny this.

But adding items to cart in iPhone and Kindle Fire don't work in three major Shopping Cart extensions from Joomla.

If you go to any of these 3 demos:

1. http://demo.virtuemart.net/ - VIRTUEMART
2. http://default.j2store.net/ - J2STORE
3. http://joomdonationdemo.com/eshop/ - ESHOP

And try to add any item to cart the items seem to be added properly but when visiting the cart there are no items in there.

I have tested successfully in:

1. Desktop Windows 7 Computers (Firefox, Chrome)
2. And Android devices with versions 4.2.1 and 4.4.2

But on these devices the Add to cart items fail, they don't show on cart

1. iPhone (iOS 10.2.1)
2. Kindle Fire 5th Generation (OS 5.3.21)

Comment: I think the problem is with your phone - have you tried using another person's iPhone?

Comment: I have an iPhone 5C and I just upgraded to the latest iOS version which is 10.3.1 and still does not works but in someone elses phone in this case an iPhone 6, it does works. Are these phones really different regarding the software they used? I mean the iOS inside iPhone 5C and iPhone 6? Or what might be the problem?

Comment: I suspect there is something on your iPhone causing this (an installed software).

Comment: Do you think if I reset the iPhone will make it work?

Comment: I just reset my iphone and it works now.